# Japanese language detection using java langdetect library

Tags: java, encoding, nlp

I have a problem with language detection for Japanese language using [java library](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/):

Using Japanese text, I'm trying to detect it's text language, but instead of expected "ja" I got "en". Has anybody seen this problem before?

What is the expected output?

```
[ja:0.9999952022259697]
```

What do you see instead?

```
[en:0.9999952022259697]
```

Original issue description with Japanese text in attachments you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/issues/detail?id=36)

Comment: Are your sure that file contains Japanese? What encoding is it, anyway? I tried interpreting it as EUC-JP, SJIS, UTF-16, and also various non-Japanese encodings. So far I am unable to see any Japanese text in it. Could this be some binary data dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a problem related to the encoding of the input file (if that file contains Japanese at all -- I am not convinced it does).

The Java library you linked to assumes -- according to the documentation -- that the input is given as a `String` object. This means it **assumes the encoding has already been correctly guessed** and the input byte sequence been converted to a **Java string.**

When you use the library, you must make sure that is the case, i.e. if you are dealing with texts in unknown encodings (such as Japanese EUC-JP or SJIS), you must detect the encoding first and convert the string properly.

(Because of these reasons, good language detectors are able to detect the encoding *and* the language at the same time, by using language-and-encoding specific internal dictionaries.)

Comment: Hi jogojapan, thank you for your answer. You're absolutely right that problem in file encoding. I've saved this file to UTF8 and problem disappeared.